# Why does this ElasticSearch scan and scroll keep returning the same scroll id?

Tags: elasticsearch

So first I run the following:

```
curl -s -XGET http://localhost:9200/my_index/_search?scroll=1m&search_type=scan&size=10
```

This returns a scroll id which I then use in the first scroll request:

```
curl -s -XGET http://localhost:9200/_search/scroll?scroll=1m&scroll_id=<scroll_id from above>
```

[The documentation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-scroll.html) would lead me to believe that when I run the 2nd curl request, I should get a new scroll id.

However, it looks like I keep getting the same scroll id back.

It looks like the data coming back is different for each request so I'm assuming that everything is working.

What is going on?

Comment: Same problem at my side as well.. same scroll ID is coming all the time and i am able to see same result on my all page while doing pagination.. is there any way I can get correct and different result on all the pages.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

What you have above is correct.

The scroll_id may or may not be the same across subsequent scroll request. But the result set (hits) is definitively different in subsequent scroll calls .

The scroll_id may change over the course of multiple calls and so it is required to always pass the most recent scroll_id as the scroll_id for the subsequent request.

Comment: But what the reason? How they are doing scrolling? When they return the new one?

Comment: I also am confused by this behavior.  Not returning a different scroll_id make it impossible to support retry on failures.  I feel like the id should always change and if you call twice with the same scroll id you should get the same page back because it is assumed that was a retry of a failed call.

Comment: It is indeed confusing. A better approach would be to include the link of the next scroll request in the response, like in HATEOAS.

Comment: Same problem at my side as well.. same scroll ID is coming all the time and i am able to see same result on my all page while doing pagination.. is there any way I can get correct and different result on all the pages.

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-scroll.html

Answer (score 1):

In most of the cases scroll_id will remain same and it may change sometime, have a look at the end of this page https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/php-api/current/search_operations.html in the comments of code sample it says:

`// When done, get the new scroll_id`

`// You must always refresh your _scroll_id!  It can change sometimes`

It means getting same scroll id for subsequent requests is fine but not mandatory.