# ElasticSearch Multiple Scrolls Java API

Tags: java, scroll, elasticsearch, parallel-processing

I want to get all data from an index. Since the number of items is too large for memory I use the Scroll (nice function):

```
client.prepareSearch(index)
    .setTypes(myType).setSearchType(SearchType.SCAN)
    .setScroll(new TimeValue(60000))
    .setSize(amountPerCall)
    .setQuery(MatchAll())
    .execute().actionGet();
```

Which works nice when calling:

```
client.prepareSearchScroll(scrollId)
    .setScroll(new TimeValue(600000))
    .execute().actionGet()
```

But, when I call the former method multiple times, I get the same `scrollId` multiple times, hence I cannot scroll multiple times - in parallel.

I found http://elasticsearch-users.115913.n3.nabble.com/Multiple-scrolls-simultanious-td4024191.html which states that it is possible - though I don't know his affiliation to ES.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Related question of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25453872/why-does-this-elasticsearch-scan-and-scroll-keep-returning-the-same-scroll-id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After searching some more, I got the impression that this (same `scrollId`) is by design. After the timeout has expired (which is reset after each call [Elasticsearch scan and scroll - add to new index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28844530/elasticsearch-scan-and-scroll-add-to-new-index)).

So you can only get one opened scroll per index.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-scroll.html states:

> Scrolling is not intended for real time user requests, but rather for
>   processing large amounts of data, e.g. in order to reindex the
>   contents of one index into a new index with a different configuration.

So it appears what I wanted is not an option, on purpose - possibly because of optimization.

**Update**
As stated creating multiple scrolls cannot be done, but this is only true when the query you use for scrolling is the same. If you `scroll` for, for instance, another `type`, `index`, or just another `query`, you can have multiple `scrolls`

Answer (score 0):

You can scroll the same index in same time, this is what elasticsearch-hadoop does.

Just, don't forget that under the hood, an index is composed of multiple shards that own data, so you can scroll each shards in parallel by using:

`.setPreference("_shards:1")`